# The origin server did not find a current representation (404 error)

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, server, http-status-code-404

i have a problem. I don't know how to solve. I get an error:
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.78

I use the usual intellij idea (not ultimate). I use only two files in my project(pom.xml,MyServlet )
I tried to use jakarta, didn't help, also changed tomcat 10,9,8 version, didn't help either.It should work without intellij idea ultimate. Idk . In url i use :

http://localhost:8080/hello-servlet

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`MyServlet`

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet( urlPatterns = {"/hello-servlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        try {
            writer.println("<h2>Hello from HelloServlet</h2>");
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }


}
```